# Memory leak involving a class exported from a DLL

Tags: c++, class, dll, memory-leaks, export

I read this excellent [article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/16/exporting-c-classes-from-a-dll/) by Eli Bendersky on exporting C++ classes from a DLL.

I want to make a class that creates a button control, but this class has to be exported from a DLL. So, I followed the steps provided by Eli on his website except for one thing, which I'm going to explain near the end of this writing :)

I wrote a very simple interface IChildWindow just for testing:

```
// IChildWindow.H

class IChildWindow
{
public:
    virtual void Create(HWND hParent) = 0;
    virtual ~IChildWIndow() {} // UPDATE: Added a virtual destructor as suggested by
                               // Brandon, PaulMcKenzie and WhozCraig. 
};
```

Then for my DLL, I wrote a class that implemented this interface and exported a couple of functions -- one for allocating memory for an object of this class and returning it to the caller and another one for releasing it.

```
// ButtonControl.H
#include <Windows.H>
#include "..\MainApp\IChildWindow.H"


class ButtonControl: public IChildWindow
{
    HWND m_hButton;

public:
    ButtonControl() : m_hButton(NULL) {}
    void Create(HWND hParent);
};


// ButtonControl.CPP
#include "ButtonControl.H"

void ButtonControl::Create(HWND hParent)
{
    m_hButton = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"Hello World", WS_CHILD | 
                             WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 100, 100, hParent, NULL,
                             (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hParent, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
                             NULL);
}
```

Right below this class definition in ButtonControl.CPP are the two exported functions:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) IChildWindow * __cdecl CreateButton()
{
    return new ButtonControl();
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl DestroyButton(IChildWindow * ptrButton)
{
    delete ptrButton;
}
```

I compiled this code and my ButtonControl.DLL was created. Next I made a Windows application that used this control. I'll just skip the creation code of this app and head directly to the Window procedure where the DLL magic happened.

```
// MainProc.CPP

LRESULT CALLBACK MainProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        if(!Initialize(hWnd))
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Something went wrong!", L"Error", MB_ICONSTOP);
        return 0;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        CloseApplication();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

bool Initialize(HWND hWnd)
{
    // Load the DLL.
    m_dllButton = LoadLibrary(L"ButtonControl.DLL");
    if(m_dllButton == NULL)
        return false;

    // Once we have the DLL loaded. Import those two functions.
    CreateButton  = (LPCREATEBUTTON)GetProcAddress(m_dllButton, "CreateButton");
    DestroyButton = (LPDESTROYBUTTON)GetProcAddress(m_dllButton, "DestroyButton");

    if(CreateButton == NULL || DestroyButton == NULL)
        return false;

    // We have obtained the functions. Let's create a button.
    m_pButton = CreateButton();
    if(m_pButton != NULL)
        m_pButton->Create(hWnd);

    return true;
}

void CloseApplication()
{
    // Destroy the button.
    if(m_pButton != NULL && DestroyButton != NULL)
        DestroyButton(m_pButton);
    m_pButton = NULL;

    // Free the DLL. 
    FreeLibrary(m_dllButton);
    m_dllButton = NULL;
}
```

**A problem and a couple of questions**
The program was able to create and display the button within its client area. But every time I close the application, my debugger is reporting a memory leak. And it happens even though the DestroyButton(...) function was called with the same memory pointer acquired from CreateButton().

The one part that I didn't follow from Eli's article was where he de-allocated the memory used by his object. In his interface example, he had a "destroy" method prototype that was implemented by a class like so:

```
void destroy()
{
    delete this;
}
```

I followed that by declaring a prototype of "DestroyButton" in IChildWindow and had ButtonControl implemented it. It worked like a charm. No memory leaks.

So, my question is why is it that when I de-allocate the memory the way I did I have memory leaking, but Eli's specialize "destroy" method does not?

I'm thinking that since the "this" pointer points to the class object or an instance of it, then "delete ptrButton" is the same as "delete this."

Also, I read from another programming forum (I forgot where) that DLLs have their own memory heap separate from the process and that any memory allocated in the DLL must be released by the DLL. But then in another forum (I know I Google a lot :), they were saying that if a DLL was loaded dynamically, the process was responsible for releasing the memory allocated in the DLL.

<strike>And because of that information, I even tried de-allocating the memory for the object (delete m_pButton) in the CloseApplication function, but it didn't solve the problem.</strike> **UPDATE:** This is now working perfectly after adding a virtual destructor to IChildWindow. Please see "Solution" below.

So, could somebody please help clarify to me and to every body who is as confused as I am -- do memories allocated by a dynamically-loaded DLL be released by the owning process to prevent memory leakage? What about for statically-linked DLL? Thank you for your time :)

**Solution**

I added a virtual destructor to the IChildWindow interface as suggested by Brandon, PaulMcKenzie and WhozCraig. This solved the memory leak problem. You guys are amazing! Thank you!

Thanks again to PaulMcKenzie and drescherjm for clarifying that using the same DLL version for both the app and the DLL will use the same heap. Good day! :)

Comment: `I read from another programming forum (I forgot where) that DLLs have their own memory heap separate from the process and that any memory allocated in the DLL must be released by the DLL.` This will happen if the application that uses the DLL was compiled with a different version of Visual Studio or if you use a debug dll in a release application or release dll in a debug application.

Comment: Very unclear how the return value of CreateButton() is correlated to the m_pButton variable.  It is supposed to leak as posted.

Comment: `CreateButton(hWnd);` So what did you do with the returned value?  In addition, there is no need to check for a NULL pointer when issuing a `delete`.

Comment: @AdamKris - If you use the DLL version of the runtime library for both your application and DLL, then both of them will be using the same heap, otherwise different heaps will be used for application and DLL.

Comment: @Hans Passant and PaulMckenzie LOL, I actually assigned it to m_pButton and called Create(...). I just forgot to put it there. Thanks for pointing that out :) Will update my post.

Comment: @AdamKris - So you need to tell us the settings you used for your application and DLL.  Are both using the "MultiThreaded DLL" version of the runtime library?  If they are then there is no memory leak.  If they're not using the DLL version of the runtime, then calling `delete` on the pointer returned by `CreateButton` within the app would more than likely have crashed.

Comment: No virtual ~destructor..

Comment: @PaulMckenzie wrote "... there is no need to check for a NULL pointer when issuing a delete." 

Will keep that in mind. Thanks, Paul.

Comment: Oh and be careful when deleting `this` pointer: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/delete-this.html

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Yes, they are both using "MultiThreaded DLL" of the library :)

Comment: The lack of virtual destructor not withstanding (which I agree with), I'm still confused how `return new IChildWindow` has *anything* to do with a `ButtonControl`? Or is that not the "real" `CreateButton` function? Shouldn't that be `return new ButtonControl()` ?

Comment: @AdamKris - You should implement a virtual destructor in `IChildWindow`.  Also, I don't see how you could have even instantiated an `IChildWindow`, given that it is an abstract class.

Comment: @Brandon wrote "Oh and be careful when deleting this pointer" 
Thanks, Brandon. I like that site you shared me.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Whoa! It was supposed to be "return new ButtonControl();" LOL. It's very late here (3:45am) Sorry for the confusion. Will update post.

Comment: @AdamKris may as well update with *real* code while you're at it. You're exported `CreateButton()` takes no parameters, yet your gpa-pointer prototype passes an `HWND`. Something isn't right there either. That should be  `m_pButton = CreateButton();` with a properly declared prototype.

Comment: @AdamKris - `It was supposed to be "return new ButtonControl();"` Well, that could be your memory leak. Add an empty virtual destructor to your `IChildWindow` class and retest.  Without a virtual destructor, attempting to call `delete` on that pointer leads to undefined behavior.  Also, you should edit your post to show the real code. I am sure that `new IChildWindow` shouldn't have even compiled.

Comment: @WhozCraig wrote, "You're exported CreateButton() takes no parameters, yet your gpa-pointer prototype passes an HWND."

Hi, WhozCraig. You're right. Post updated. Thank you :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie wrote "Without a virtual destructor, attempting to call delete on that pointer leads to undefined behavior"

Thanks for pointing that out. I will update with real code.

Comment: Updated with real code. Thanks for all the help. I appreciate it :)